# Web scrapping of a website with password

Tags: download-manager

I am trying to extract all the content of a website (HTML, CSS, JS) (images and videos will be a plus).

I am looking for a tool like [HTTrack](http://www.httrack.com/) but that can access pages that require a login (I have the POST parameter's values). Does anyone know a tool like this?

If that is not possible, does anyone know a browser extension (for Chrome or Firefox) to save automatically the content of a website while browsing it? (Sort of an offline reader, but that really grab the HTML, CSS and JS.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTTrack [supports](http://httrack.kauler.com/help/Authentication) form-based and HTTP authentications:

- [Form-based authentication](http://httrack.kauler.com/help/CatchURL_tutorial)
- [HTTP authentication](http://httrack.kauler.com/help/HTTP_authentication)

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer! I have tried the "Form-based authentication" with IE before but it was not working. And it worked just fine with Firefox now. So it perfectly solved my problem! I will have a look at GNU wget as well

Answer (score 0):

You can use [GNU wget](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/):

- free and open source
- Linux, [Windows](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/wget.htm), Mac (`brew install wget`)
- CLI
- supports [authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4272770/395857), e.g. `wget http://myurl.com --user=joe --password=schmoe` or with `wget --save-cookies` + `wget --load-cookies`